# Python: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a textfile, let's call it `goodlines.txt` and I want to load it and make a list that contains each line in the text file.

I tried using the `split()` procedure like this:

```
>>> f = open('goodlines.txt')
>>> mylist = f.splitlines()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
>>> mylist = f.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Why do I get these errors? Is that not how I use `split()`? ( I am using `python 3.3.2`)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are using `str` methods on an open file object.

You can read the file as a list of lines by simply calling `list()` on the file object:

```
with open('goodlines.txt') as f:
    mylist = list(f)
```

This *does* include the newline characters. You can strip those in a list comprehension:

```
with open('goodlines.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

Comment: is there any new approach to do that? since 2024?)

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
 >>> f = open('goodlines.txt')
 >>> mylist = f.readlines()
```

`open()` function returns a file object. And for file object, there is no method like `splitlines()` or `split()`. You could use `dir(f)` to see all the methods of file object.

Comment: That is fine, but I keep getting these "\n" things at the end of each... How do I remove them without changing the textfile?

Answer (score 11):

You're not reading the file content:

```
my_file_contents = f.read()
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for further infos

You could, without calling `read()` or `readlines()` loop over your file object:

```
f = open('goodlines.txt')
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

If you want a list out of it (without `\n` as you asked)

```
my_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

Comment: The list comprehension does **not** strip newlines. You may as well just call `list(f)` instead, to the same effect as your current code.

Comment: @samuele-mattiuzzo "my_list = [line for line in f]" ALSO made a list with \n at the end of each, even tho it is not in the text file. But should split work when it is read?

Comment: As Mr Pieters promptly pointed out, the `\n` needs to be striped away anyway.