# retrieving string from file in python and changing tuples

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples, stringio

I have a serious snag in my programming, and it might be an easy fix, but anytime I find something that looks like the right forum post, it's not quite right.

I'm using a file to store data created from one part of my program, like a high score, number of times played, and player name.

I store all this data just fine in the file with a tuple set of ("string key", key's value).  I like the ease of retrieval with the dict() command, and have worked with both, 
but 
I have to convert the entire data set into a string in order to store it to the file.

And

When I retrieve the data for the next time I open the program, I can't seem to add to the "number of times played" or change the players name for the high score..

It looks a little like this:

```
import sys
import random
import pickle
save=open ("(path to file)/newgame.txt", 'r+')
save.seek(0)
hiscore=(save.readlines())
def Savedata():
    global save
    global name
    global highscore
    global numplays
#this is where the ideal code would split, modify, and repack the data from the file    
    save.seek(0)
    save.write(str (hiscore))
print (save)
save.seek(0)
save.close()
```

Can anyone give me any direction add to what I should look into..  I'm on my phone and can't give proper code examples right now...

Comment: You may want to clarify you problem. I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I needed to convert a set of tuples of ("string", integer) into a string, and back into a set of tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using an actual serializing library? For example `json` is very useful. Particularly if you're just dumping a dict.

For example:

```
>>> d = {'level':2, 'position':[2,3]}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(d) # or json.dump(d, save) in your code
'{"position": [2, 3], "level": 2}'
```

That way you could simply load the string using `json.loads`. Or directly a file using `json.load`.

Comment: Thanks, I really am beginning in this endeavor, I was using what I knew, and I don't know json at all, I will try and learn more about it, maybe that will be the best solution.  At the time, I knew about tuples and dicts and lists and saving and recalling strings.  I'm always willing to add more to my knowledge base for programming :-)

Comment: Revision: I haven't fixed it yet, but i noticed that the run of the code i was trying also alerted me to an error when i tried to split the file back into tuples.  '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split' ... which i was ignoring.  There was a post that helped a lot [here, posted by safeer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569679/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-split) if anyone in the community has this problem and can't solve it like i couldn't

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you follow my example of using json? Post maybe a minimal working exmaple so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: I have too much to post, this will have to be a second question, the short version is that you have successfully answered my original problem