# Get the differences in two files

Tags: python-3.x

I have got two files and I need the lines which are different in these two files.
The lines are not in order in these two files.

I was trying to use following script

```
file1 = open("test1.txt","r")
file2 = open("test2.txt","r")

lines1 = hosts0.readlines()

for i,lines2 in enumerate(file2):
    if lines2 != lines1[i]:
        print ("line ", i, " in File2 is different \n")
        print (lines2)
    else:
        print ("Its similar")
```

However this only compares the lines at the same line number in both files.

Example of my files :

`File1:`

```
User 1 is Sam and PC in VLAN Trust
User10 is Tom and PC in VLAN Sales
Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin
```

`File2:`

```
Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin
User 1 is Sam and PC in VLAN Trust
User10 is Tom and PC in VLAN Sales
User20 is Donald and VLAN is Trust
```

I want the output to tell me the missing line in File1 which is there in File2. And as long as any line is common between two files irrespective of different line number it should not list it as difference.

Comment: How large are these files? If they both easily fit into memory, you might simply use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html): `diff = set(file1).symmetric_difference(set(file2))` This won't keep information about line numbers though.

Comment: Hi Lukas, The files are about 10 MB , the command you suggests lists the difference and doesn't tell which file is missing those line. But will suffice for me as only one of the file is missing several lines in my case. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It opens the files, reads the lines.

It then goes through the lines and compares each line in file2 to the lines in file1. If the line is in both, the variable `inboth` becomes true.

I added a print command at the end so I could check it works. Just change the variable names to fit the ones you use and then add it onto your current program. Hope this is a help

```
f1 = open("file1.txt","r")
f2 = open("file2.txt","r")

lines1 = f1.readlines()
lines2 = f2.readlines()

for i in lines2:
    inboth = False
    for x in lines1:
        if i == x:
            inboth = True
    if inboth != True:
        print("The line: \n",i,"\nis in file 2 but not file 1\n")
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html) which is a built-in module in python. Here is an example:

```
import difflib

file1_lines = [
    'User 1 is Sam and PC in VLAN Trust',
    'User10 is Tom and PC in VLAN Sales',
    'Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin'
]

file2_lines = [
    'Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin',
    'User 1 is Sam and PC in VLAN Trust',
    'User10 is Tom and PC in VLAN Sales',
    'User20 is Donald and VLAN is Trus'
]

differ = difflib.Differ()
diffs = list(differ.compare(file1_lines, file2_lines))

for diff in diffs:
    print(diff)
```

Output:

```
+ Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin
  User 1 is Sam and PC in VLAN Trust
  User10 is Tom and PC in VLAN Sales
- Harry is User 6 and in VLAN Fin
+ User20 is Donald and VLAN is Trus
```

From [docs for `Differ`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ), the meaning of those initial two-letter codes:

> - `'- '` line unique to sequence 1
> - `'+ '` line unique to sequence 2
> - `'  '` line common to both sequences
> - `'? '` line not present in either input sequence

Here "sequence 1" is the first argument to `differ.compare()` and "sequence 2" is the second one, both of which are to be lists of strings to be compared.

---

My easier interpretation:

- lines beginning with `'+ '` are those added in `file2_lines` that were absent in `file1_lines`
- lines beginning with `'- '` are those absent in `file2_lines` but were there in `file1_lines`
- lines beginning with `'? '` are those that got changed ([**up to a certain threshold**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965748/how-to-set-custom-ratio-for-difflibs-compare-function))
- lines beginning with `'  '` are those not modified between the two set of lines

**Edit**

I see that in my output the line `Harry is user...` is not shown to be unchanged. If I *now* understand it right you want it to be shown as unchanged. You can get around this by first sorting the list of strings and then comparing the sorted lists. Just change the line with call to `compare` with this:

```
diffs = list(differ.compare(sorted(file1_lines), sorted(file2_lines)))
```

Comment: Got following error, it appears some issue with my python library //      File "C:\Python\lib\difflib.py", line 912, in compare
    cruncher = SequenceMatcher(self.linejunk, a, b)
  File "C:\Python\lib\difflib.py", line 216, in __init__
    self.set_seqs(a, b)
  File "C:\Python\lib\difflib.py", line 228, in set_seqs
    self.set_seq2(b)
  File "C:\Python\lib\difflib.py", line 282, in set_seq2
    self.__chain_b()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\difflib.py", line 330, in __chain_b
    n = len(b)
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()

Comment: @Zoro99 may you need to a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17570045/3375713). Make sure `file1_lines` and `file2_lines` are lists of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
file1 = open("test1.txt","r")
file2 = open("test2.txt","r")

lines1 = file1.readlines()
lines2 = file2.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines2):
    if line not in lines1:
        print("Line {} in file 2 is not in file 1".format(i))

for i, line in enumerate(lines1):
    if line not in lines2:
        print("Line {} in file 1 is not in file 2".format(i))

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

This works for both files. The line count starts from zero though. You can fix it by writing `i+1` in the format arguments. Also remember to close files after your script has finished working with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f: lines1=f.readlines()
with open('file2.txt','r') as f: lines2=f.readlines()
diff=False
for line,idx in zip(lines2,range(len(lines2))):
    if line not in lines1:
        print("line %d of file2 is missing in file1:\n%s"%(idx,line))
        diff=True
if not diff:
    print("similar")
```