# Python Issue: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split, attributeerror

I am trying to make a program that opens a text file and reads it out one word at a time in a window. I get an error on the first line here:

```
fileWords = file.split()
for line in fileWords:
    text.setText("{}".format(line))
    time.sleep(sec)
```

This is what I get when the program gets to this bit:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: AttributeError: '\_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569679/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Comment: While it is clear that you are a beginner programmer, I would like to thank you for asking a clear question with a clear description of an error you are getting based on code you actually wrote yourself. Not a lot of that going on these days and it's nice to see a beginner question that is properly asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the contents of the file first:

```
fileWords = f.read().split()
```

Also, don't use `file` as it is a python built-in class!

Another option, if you want to iterate over lines (not words):

```
fileLines = f.readlines()
for line in fileLines:
    ...
```

Comment: reserved by python 2 only BTW.