# Code not reading the file, error object Len() MASTERLIST

Tags: python

it's my first time posting here. I am doing one of my assignments, and I am having a hard time.

[Here is what my professor is asking for - click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Nh0.png)

This is the code I have:

```
option1=open("BrandVB.txt", "r")
option2=open("BrandA.txt", "r")
option3=open("BrandC.txt", "r")
option4=open("BrandX.txt", "r")

#Creating a master lits
li = [option1, option2,option3, option4]

#Searching part numbers based on brand
brand=input("Enter the brand: ")
for i in range(len(li)):
    for j in range(len(li[i])):
        if brand==li[i][j]:
            pos=j
for i in range(len(li)):
    print(li[i][pos])
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Desktop/LAB10/LAB10.py", line 17, in <module>
    for j in range(len(li[i])):
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: AttributeError: '\_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569679/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to just `open` the file, you also need to `.read()` from it. Here's one way to do it:

```
with open("BrandVB.txt", "r") as a, open("BrandA.txt", "r") as b, open("BrandC.txt", "r") as c, open("BrandX.txt", "r") as d:
    option1 = a.read()
    option2 = b.read()
    option3 = c.read()
    option4 = d.read()
```

---

[Python - Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thank you! I fixed and I am not getting the '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len() error. However I am getting this error now:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Desktop/LAB10/LAB10.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(li[i][pos])
NameError: name 'pos' is not defined

Comment: However I am getting this error now: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Desktop/LAB10/LAB10.py", line 21, in <module> print(li[i][pos]) NameError: name 'pos' is not defined

Comment: Just a guess, but you may want to initiate `pos` before the loop.

Comment: I did not understand sorry :/

Comment: It'd help if you explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read in the texts. Right now you just open the files as an IO Wrapper without using these to input the data.

Try this:

```
with open("BrandVB.txt", "r") as file:
    option1 = file.read()
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed and I am not getting the '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len() error. However I am getting this error now: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Desktop/LAB10/LAB10.py", line 21, in <module> print(li[i][pos]) NameError: name 'pos' is not defined