# Copy a single row from one csv to another csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need some direction on how to append a single row from one csv file to end of a list in another csv file.

The following is my code but I'm having trouble with copying only the second row to exclude the header plus it is appending with a skipped row.

```
with open('Preliminary.csv', 'r') as f1:
    original = f1.read()

with open('Primary.csv', 'a') as f2:
    f2.write('\n')
    f2.write(original)
```

The problem with it is it's copying and appending the entire file and also placing it a few lines below the last in the destination csv file. I have a header that I want to avoid from copying over and only one row after that which is how my file output is designed.

Thanks for any input you may provide

Comment: it is appending the whole file because you are providing the whole file object as the input to write out. do you know how to iterate over a file?

Comment: I don't know how to do it while excluding the first row (header).  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share some example input and output? Have you done any research on text file IO in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is with bash:

```
   sed '2!d' Preliminary.csv >> Primary.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, DB Wizz.  How does that look within my code?  Do I only enter that line?  Sorry I'm not familiar with bash.  I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Bash is just the (linux/macos) command line. Is this problem part of your job duties, or are you doing it just to learn python?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try something like this:
assuming you want to copy index 2 of f2 to f1

```
f1.loc[f2.index[2]] = f2.iloc[0]
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it makes sense or if this answer can be improved.

Once you are certain that both your dataframes are up and running you just run the piece of code I suggested adjusting to the index you actually want to copy into the position you want it moved to.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I'm not too sure where to insert that into the code.  I apologize but I'm just starting out with Python

Comment: Thank you for the added info.  I added the line to the end of my original code and it is getting this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Append.py", line 9, in <module>
    f1.loc[f2.index[2]] = f2.iloc[0]
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: Also, yes, it's the second row that I want to copy.  I'm not sure if I placed the code in the proper place.

Comment: I don't know much about your data but I am assuming that there is some text data in the dataframes you are trying to create and there is a chance you are not actually reading in the data. Check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569679/python-attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-split

Comment: I'm pulling in five columns and one row of numbers from a csv file to copy plus a header that I do not want to copy.  I looked at the page you referred me to and I am a bit confused on how I can apply it to a read of a csv file?  Thanks again for you help and any additional comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: OP isn't using `pandas` so suggesting an answer using `pandas` does not make sense here

Comment: Pandas is overkill for this, it's entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `next` method on the file object to simply skip the header and write the second row to the file you want. Your code ends up looking like this for conciseness:

```
with open('Preliminary.csv', 'r') as fin, open('Primary.csv', 'a') as fout:
    next(fin)  # skipping the headers since we don't want them
    second = next(fin)  # grabbing the second line of the file
    fout.write('\n')
    fout.write(second)
```